# Recursive linked list type alias in Go

Tags: c, go, data-structures, struct, linked-list

I am trying to translate some C code to Go and I'm wondering if there is a Go equivalent to the following linked list types:

```
typedef struct TOKENLIST {
  token item;
  struct TOKENLIST *next;
} token_list_elt, *token_list;
```

So far it appears that I would have to create both types separately like this:

```
type token_list struct {
    item token
    next *token_list
}
type token_list_elt struct {
    item token
    next *token_list_elt
}
```

This is not such a big deal for this example, but there are lots linked list types like these I need to translate and some of them have many aliases and/or struct fields.

Comment: Go is not very good at implementing generic data structures.

Comment: `token_list_elt` is the struct, and `token_list` is a pointer to the struct.  Is there a reason that you cannot simply translate the code by explicitly instantiating all `token_list` types as `&token_list_elt{ ... }` in the go code?

Comment: This was a bad example, other struct definitions are used for more than just two types where one type is a pointer like I showed here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But why not use it like this:

```
type linkedList struct {
    item token
    next *linkedList
}

...

tokenList := linkedList{}
tokenListElt := linkedList{}
```

Are different struct types so important?

Comment: I think you are right. Having different types of lists is really not that beneficial. I will just use one type.